# Making links clickable, showing scrollbars in every mobile browser

Tags: android, css, html

On my page http://goo.gl/ kNAXq (remove the space in your browser, please don't replace the link here as I don't want google to link this page to my site.) when you click on the S in the MAP using your average pc/mac browser you get a popup with scrolling bars, which is intended. I do not see those borders on my android mobile phone's standard browser, though, what doesn't fit in is cut off there. What could be the cause?

Also *Routenplanung* and *Zur Karte* are not clickable even though they are valid links:

```
<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=49.4538517,11.0773238&daddr=49.455856,11.074445&dirflg=w&hl=de">Routenplanung</a>
```

and

```
<a style="a:link {text-decoration:underline;}" href="#mapdiv">Zur Karte</a>
```

Why do they not work as intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no scroll bars in mobile browsers, for the most part. You just need to drag the content in the div up, however, the div is too small to properly grab on to (at least based on what I see on the desktop, it's taking forever to load on my phone...).

Links don't work because you have another element on top of it... The <i> (why i?) is positioned absolute and over the top of the links.

First of all, <i> is for italicizing text and it's deprecated. A better setup, I believe, would be to put the shadow on the containing div. Just get rid of the i element. One downside is , you'll need to change how the background color is implemented on the grey table cells.

Just add shadow as a class to the div.

Then alter the css, like so:

```
.results-bl.shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 1, 1, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 1, 1, 0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 1, 1, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Did you find the cause for the longer loading time on mobile phones? I encounter the same problem.

Comment: Nope, assumed it was a server issue... but maybe not. Now I'm just getting a connection timeout.

Comment: I am trying it with android in virtualbox right now. Works very fast. But using it on my android it was painfully slow. Are you using WLAN with your mobile?

Comment: Yep... Going through the same wireless network as the laptop I'm accessing it from...

Comment: So to conclude: It is slow on real smartphones but not on android in virtual machines and not in normal browsers. Tough challenge. I am looking into the <i> issue.

Comment: I don't understand what to remove/change regarding the <i> please elaborate.

Comment: So, for the smartphone stuff... I'd disable the scripts, see how it loads. Then re-enable it in sections to figure out what is causing the slow down. Pay special attention to stuff that may use mobile special stuff, like location, touch, etc...

Comment: I need the location of the phone so I cannot switch this off. When your smartphone works with it -ie no timeout - does the app show your proper position? PS: Please have a look at the page again, I changed some things according to your ideas, links are clickable but now the shadow seems to be missing.

Comment: You have a box-shadow: none; overriding your inset, due to higher specificity and placement after... it's on line 552 of style.css

Comment: Good, but now the grey areas don't have a shadow.